# How to integrate steelseries in Angular project?

Tags: angular, steelseries

I am trying to integrate [steelseries](https://nicolas-van.github.io/steelseries/) in an Angular project. Following [their example](https://github.com/nicolas-van/steelseries), my code looks like this:
**app.component.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!-- <body (BeforeRender)="displayCanvas($event)"> -->
  <body >
    <div>
      <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script src="C:\\ProiecteAngular\\Test\\TestDev\\node_modules\\steelseries\\srcdocs\\index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as steelseries from "steelseries";
import { Compass } from "steelseries";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
 // template: `<canvas #myCanvas></canvas>`
})
//export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'TestDev';
  // @ViewChild('myCanvas', { static: true })
  // myCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  displayCanvas(event) {
    const compass = new Compass(document.querySelector("myCanvas"), {
      size: 200
    });
  }
  // public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  // ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  //   this.context = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
  //   const compass = new Compass(document.querySelector("myCanvas"), {
  //     size: 200
  //   });
  // }
}
```

With this code, nothing is displayed on my web page. My thought is that canvas is not rendered correctly. I have seen that this could be done using `ViewChild`. I did some unsuccessfully tests (see the commented code from .ts file). What am I missing or doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to add index.js file to html.

example

[stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sz9hmd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

***html***

```
<div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

***script***

```
ngOnInit() {
  const compass = new Compass(document.querySelector('#myCanvas'), {
    size: 200,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working.  All i have to do now is to discover how to apply different properties to the component.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad the issue was resolved.  @Ionut

I will add an example usage for you in the link I shared.

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need the script tag in the index.html. You are importing the js in the app.component.ts file.
2. you use `document.querySelector` in the `displayCanvas` function. To make that work you would need to prefix `myCanvas` with `#` for the id like `document.querySelector("#myCanvas")` and add `id="myCanvas"` to the canvas html tag. (That is not the same as just `#myCanvas` as attribute in the tag.
   See an working example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gol2jx?file=src/app/app.component.html
   But that way is not best practise for angular, because you could not use that for multiple components, because `document.querySelector("#myCanvas")` looks for the id in the whole html document and uses only the first.
   To make it more 'angular-like' you would need as you already mentioned `ViewChild`. Just use `const compass = new Compass(this.myCanvas.nativeElement, ... )`